# Golang передача значений в метод

Tags: golang, указатели

Имею такой пример из литературы (имена мeтодов одинаковые для простоты)

```
func (p *Person) setName(name string){ p.Name = name }
func (p Person) setName(name string){ p.Name = name }
```

т.е. в первом случае передаем указатель на структуру, во втором по значению. Почему обращение к полю происходит одинаково, не через "разименование" указателя? По идее должно быть (*p).Name = name. Буду крайне признателен всем ответившим.

Comment: Я не думаю, что вы получите другой ответ кроме "потому что это удобно". Всяко лучше оператора `->` в C/C++, от которого болят пальцы.

Comment: Так сделано специально. Компилятору очевидно, что хотел сделать программист.

Comment: К стати второй пример это баг :) https://play.golang.org/p/ROUgLFfMWEO. Поскольку `p Person` это копия структуры...

Comment: `(*p).Name = name` и происходит просто за вас это делает компилятор. Поскольку Го запрещает арифметику с указателями с этим указателем в принципе делать больше нечего...